# Multi-OS persistence USB

Tags: multi-boot, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, persistence

I have some USB flash drives with different persistent OS that I use when I have to work on public or shared PCs, so that I don't have to familiarize with a new environment every time and I can be sure that there are no malwares in the systems I work with. Now, I'm wondering if there is a way to install multiple persistent OSs in the same (huge) USB flash drive.

All the OSs I use are all Linux-based, not sure if it is important or useful.

I would prefer an open source solution; still, it is not essential.

Comment: What prevents you to install another OS using the same method done previously?

Comment: @CaldeiraG I can't figure out how to install the new OS aside the first one.

Answer (score 0):

[YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) can do this. Note that it needs to explicitly support OSes you want to add. The list is pretty extensive and some derivatives work with their base distro's profile, too.

The tool is pretty self-explanatory, just make sure to pick the right version: CSM or UEFI, depending on your preferred boot method.

Comment: I tried it but when I boot my PC from the USB it produces a black screen with a white blinking `_` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing is, nothing prevents you from installing OSes onto USB drives the same way you would on an internal drive, especially on Linux distros. Tools like YUMI are fine, but in my experience, the way they configure persistent storage is rather unstable. Usually the way I do it is I have two USB drives, one I want to install my OSes on and one I want to use for the installation drives, and I just partition the drives before the way I want.

Comment: It is what I did to install the first OS in my USB drives. The problem is that I don't know how to install the second one aside the first instead ov overwriting it.

Comment: It's easy. You can partition everything beforehand using a tool like GParted with multiple filesystems and then install root to each one using each installer. So say you have multiple drives, one of Ubuntu, one of Manjaro, and one of Fedora. You can boot into Ubuntu, use GParted to partition your USB drive into ALL the partitions you need for your installations manually. Then, you can install Ubuntu with the GRUB bootloader, reboot, boot into your Manjaro drive and install Manjaro on another partition without the bootloader, and do the same for Fedora and manually add boot entries/update GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

SARDU does everything in one single pass, yumi does not.